# File read goes into infinite loop when file to be read is already open

Tags: c++, encryption, file-io

I wrote this Code to make a journal or Diary. It takes input, encrypts it and stores it in file called "yourDiary.txt". When asked to decrypt, it asks for password(currently "pwd"). If Password matches, it decrypts "yourDiary.txt" to "yourDiaryDecrypted.txt". It generally works fine. But if "yourDiary.txt" is open in a text editor, the program goes into an infinite loop and "yourDiaryDecrypted.txt" grows indefinitely. somebody please tell the reson for that.

I could not find the source of the problem so uploading the whole code.

```
    // writing on a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


string encryptDecrypt(string toEncrypt) {                       //encryption,decryption function
    char key = 'K'; //Any char will work
    string output = toEncrypt;

    for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.size(); i++)
        output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;

    return output;
}
int main () {
  int mode;cout<<"Enter 1 to add new entry, 0 to see the diary\n"; cin>>mode;
  ofstream f ("yourDiary.txt",ios::app);
  time_t now=time(0);
  char *ltm=ctime(&now);
  string line,line2,pwd;
  string encrypted = encryptDecrypt(ltm);                       //timestamp encrypted and added to file
  string decrypted;
  f<<encryptDecrypt("**");                              //to find end of file
  f<<"\n\n\n\n";
  f << encrypted << "\n\n";
  if(mode==1){
    cout<<"speak your heart out. when you feel better enter **++**\n";
    for(;;){
        getline(cin,line);
        if(line=="**++**"){
            encrypted=encryptDecrypt(line);
            f << encrypted <<"\n";
            break;                                  //end cuurrent data entry
        }
        else{
            encrypted=encryptDecrypt(line);
            f << encrypted <<"\n";                          //line to file
        }
    }
    f.close();
  }
  if (mode==0){
    cout<<"enter password\n"; 
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,pwd);
    if(pwd=="pwd"){                                 //encryption of password
        ofstream dia("yourDiaryDecrypted.txt",ios::trunc);
        fstream f("yourDiary.txt");
      NEXT: getline(f,line);
        decrypted=encryptDecrypt(line);
        if (decrypted!="**++**"){
            dia<<decrypted<<"\n";
            goto NEXT;                                  //restart loop
        }
        else{
            getline(f,line2);
            decrypted=encryptDecrypt(line2);
            if(decrypted=="**"){
                dia<<decrypted<<"\n";
                goto NEXT;                              //restart loop
            }
            else{
                goto EXIT;                              //break loop
            }
        }
      EXIT: dia.close();f.close();
        cout<<"You can now see your decrypted diary\n  :)\n";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"wait for the password. I will give it to you in due time\n";
    }
  }
  cout<<"press enter to continue";
  cin.ignore();
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to give a definitive answer without sample input that triggers your error, but... There is probably a linefeed in the input stream after  `cin>>mode;`. Possibly other junk, too. It is possible that you produce an end of line character when you XOR the input with the key. Test your input for success. It's really easy to get an infinite loop on an undetected file error. Reconsider the `goto` statements. A `while (!quit)` loop should do the job.

Comment: Under normal condition code works fine. It only gets into infinite loop when trying to decrypt while `yourdiary.txt` is open elsewhere. Adding a new entry is always fine.

Comment: The file not being open because it couldn't be opened is an error. You check for no errors. Don't expect exceptions to be thrown. The default for IOstreams is no exceptions. `while (getline(f,line))` in place of the `goto` will probably solve all of your problems and eliminate the need for the end of file marker string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not in your code its when when you run it and enter the data. I ran your code when it asks in mode == 1
 `cout<<"speak your heart out. when you feel better enter **++**\n";`
if you don't type `**++**` when you make yourDiary.txt with it will go into an infinite loop because of this

```
NEXT: getline(f,line);
    decrypted=encryptDecrypt(line);
    if (decrypted!="**++**"){
        dia<<decrypted<<"\n";
        goto NEXT;
```

its never going to find `**++**` if you don't enter it therefore it keeps looping. It worked when I entered `**++**` or you can use a while loop as suggested in the comments instead of goto. This needs to be inside the if(mode == 1)

```
 f<<encryptDecrypt("**"); 
 f<<"\n\n\n\n";
 f << encrypted << "\n\n";
```

otherwise it will print this in the the yourdiary.txt if you run mode == 0 and if you run mode == 0 again it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I have to add `**++**` at the end of every entry. Otherwise i will have to end the code with `Ctrl+C`. I do add the `**++**` everytime.

Comment: Try that I hope that fixes the problem just let me know if it doesn't ill keep trying to fix it if it doesn't.